# jquery-file-upload plugin

Tags: jquery, grails, jquery-plugins, grails-plugin, grails-controller

I am trying to implement a jquery file upload for grails.  I am using this plugin here [grails jquery-file-upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) and here [grails plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/jquery-file-upload)

unfortunately, there densest seem to be any document ion on how to implement it in a grails environment.  I have been struggling with it for days now.  I am able to get the front end to work but I am unable to process the upload.  Does anyone have a working example or know of a tutorial for grails?  I would really appreciate any help.  Or, if there is a better jquery upload plugin, let me know too.

thanks,
jason

Answer (score 2):

I've personally had luck with this one: 
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
It supports drag-and-drop and multiple file uploads.  People seem to like it as well.

Another one I've never personally used, but I hear good things about: http://www.uploadify.com
Uses flash though.

Comment: ajax-upload is GPL2.0, whereas jquery-file-upload is MIT

Answer (score 0):

You could try using http://swfupload.org/

> SWFUpload is a small JavaScript/Flash library to get the best of both
>   worlds. It features the great upload capabilities of Flash and the
>   accessibility and ease of HTML/CSS.